# KCFinder show blank window when upload the image with ckeditor

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, ckeditor, kcfinder

This is working fine on local system but not working on server.

KCFInder configuration detail

kcfinder/conf/config.php

$_CONFIG = array(

// GENERAL SETTINGS

```
'disabled' => false,
'uploadURL' => "http://mylocal/uploads/ckeditorImages",
'uploadDir' => "/var/www/html/mylocal/public/uploads/ckeditorImages",
'theme' => "default",
```

Answer (score 0):

the `uploadDir` seems to be incorrect.
 
`/var/www/html/mylocal/public/uploads/ckeditorImages` shouldn't work on your server.

I think you should look over to 
[this post for more informations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503933/how-to-change-the-default-browse-directory-for-images-in-kcfinder)  or search on  [KCFinder project](https://github.com/sunhater/kcfinder/blob/master/conf/config.php).

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is correct path of server.  still getting same issue.